# Prove that $A+B$ with $A^{-1}$ compact and $B$ $A$-compact is Fredholm with index zero

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A:D(A)\rightarrow X$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $X$. Let $B:D(B)(\supset D(A))\rightarrow X$ be $A$-compact. I have been trying to prove that if $0\in\rho(A)$ and $A^{-1}$ is compact, then $A+B$ is a Fredholm operator with index zero. I could use a standard result:

Suppose that $T:D(T)\rightarrow X$ is a Fredholm operator and $B:D(B)\rightarrow X$ is $T$-compact. Then (i) $T + B$ is a Fredholm operator, (ii) $\text{ind}\,(T + B) = \text{ind} \,T$.

Returning to the question, all we need to show is that $A$ is Fredholm with zero index. Is this correct?